# javascript doesn't keep new tag content oustide a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, tags

I have a problem that I may know how to fix it but I don't know why it even exist. 
in html code I have an empty tag *ul* :

```
     .....
     <ul></ul>
      ....
```

then in javascript I have a function that  add content to this tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
......
function test(){
    $("ul").html("<li>blablabla</li>...");
    alert( $("ul").html());  //alert 1 work like a charm it show the exact content
}
 test();
 alert( $("ul").html()); //alert 2 show that ul is empty :(
 .....
 }
```

Now I want to keep my code organised by using funtions but this problem forced me to stay inside the same function. waiting for your help.thanks

Comment: I don't think this is your complete code.

Comment: Code as shown shows the html in both alerts [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6eh0r8sn/). So there must be something else going on that you are not showing

Comment: what is the issue? behavior is fine to me.

Comment: actually the code is more complex and long but I will try to  publish a simple

Comment: It's working for me.. http://jsbin.com/cidixe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys finally I found where is the problem, this is an update of my question :

> I have a problem that I may know how to fix it but I don't know why it
>   even exist.  in html code I have an empty tag *ul* :
>
> ```
>      .....
>      <ul></ul>
>       ....
> ```
>
> then in javascript I have a function that  add content to this tag:
>
> ```
>   $(document).ready(function(){
>       ......
>       test();
>       alert( $("ul").html()); //alert 2 show that ul is empty :(
>       .....
>      }
>
>  function test(selected){
>      $.post("http://localhost/htmlTraining/php/liste.php",{classe: selected},function(data){ 
>          $("ul").html('<img id="next" src="images/next.ico"/><img id="prev" src="images/prev.ico"/>'+data);
>            alert( $("ul").html());  //alert 1 work like a charm it show the exact content
>        });
> }
> ```
>
> Now I want to keep my code organised by using funtions but this
>   problem forced me to stay inside the same function. waiting for your
>   help.thanks

in this code the `alert` 2 doen't work because it runs before the the function `test` finishs its execution. and by this time `tag ul` is still empty. I found this problem by using the `function setinterval()` to `alert`2, after a while `alert`2 works fine.

what I have learned is :

```
function1();
function2();
```

if you want to use data from function1 inside function2 make sure that they are ready. :)